# Schedule apex class to run every day

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, class, scheduled-apex

I want to make some rollups on a custom objects via a scheduled Apex class.
I managed to test the rollup via an Apex trigger, which fired whenever I edited the custom object. Now I want to run it daily, so I'm sure that my custom object collects all the necessary data from the other related objects.

Here's the class where the rollup happens

```
public class QuotaRollup {
    public void sumOpportunityAmounts(List<Quota__c> qta) {
        for(Quota__c q:qta) {
            set<id> ids=new set<id>();
            ids.add(q.Sales_Rep__c);
            Date startDate = q.Quota_Start_Date__c;
            Date finishDate = q.Quota_End_Date__c;

            //select the opportunities for the current sales rep between the specified period
            list<opportunity> op=[select o.id, o.Estimated_Net_Amount__c, o.CloseDate from Opportunity o where o.Sales_Rep__c in:ids and o.CloseDate >=: startDate and o.CloseDate <=: finishDate];

            ... //do the rollup ...
        }
    }
}
```

This function worked correctly via the trigger. I passed the **trigger.new** parameter into the sumOpportunityAmmounts function, and I got the right answer.

Now, I tried to change the trigger into an Apex class that implements the schedulable class.
Here's what it looks like:

```
public class scheduleQuotaRollup implements Schedulable {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
        List<Quota__c> qta = [SELECT Name, Actual_Amount__c, Forecast__c, Funnel__c, Quota_End_Date__c, Quota_Start_Date__c, Sales_Rep__c FROM Quota__c];
        QuotaRollup qsoar = new QuotaRollup();
        qsoar.sumOpportunityAmounts(qta);
    }
}
```

I created a schedule for this class, to run at 14:00 each day, but it didn't work. In the **All Scheduled Jobs** section (in SETUP) I can see that it started running, but it didn't do what it was supposed to do.

I also tried something more un-orthodox: I added the same code (without the "Schedulable" things) into the same trigger where it worked before, but instead of using the **trigger.new** pointer, I used the SELECT statement (from above), so it would work on all the objects, not just the one that I edited. That didn't work either...

Also, if I run the SELECT query in the developer console, I get the values back, so the select query is correct.

What could be wrong? Should I create the list of Quota objects in a different way?

Comment: First thing you need to remove the query out of the for loop. Try debugging the scheduler class there might be some errors. I think you need to do this in scheduled batch as there might be huge volume of records.

Comment: @rahulgawale is right here .... you probably want  to use Batch for this and to schedule it.

Comment: I only have 12 Quota__c objects, so there aren't a lot of records, but thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a look at batch.